# SQL Update statment from file

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "Soft_orders" which has two columns "id_order(primary key)" & "id_customer".
I have .sql file which has data for these two columns like the format below, (first value is id_order and second is id_customer)

```
(1, 1),
(2, 1),
(3, 1),
(4, 1),
(5, 1),
(6, 2),
(11, 2).........
```

I simply want to update the values of id_customer in the table by importing this .sql file.
I would like to know which sql statment I have to use so that it update the "id_customer" value.

Comment: Do we work on the basis that the table soft_orders contains all the id_order present in the .sql file (which looks to be in an odd format) or may some records in the .sql file not be present in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file into a second table and then use an update join:

```sql
UPDATE Soft_orders t1
INNER JOIN Table_From_File t2
    ON t2.id_order = t1.id_order
SET t1.id_customer = t2.id_customer;
```

Comment: i have the data in one file, i had posted its contents in my question

Comment: @Revol Begins your last comment suggests you think this answer inappropriate, I think it;s correct can you clarify your comment?

Comment: @tim thanks for reply, i had used this statment
`UPDATE soft_orders t1
INNER JOIN soft_testorders t2
    ON t2.id_order = t1.id_order
SET id_customer = t2.id_customer;`

but it says `#1052 - Column 'id_customer' in field list is ambiguous
`

Comment: Then maybe the `SET` clause needs an alias.

Comment: so what shall i do then?